# Adding values to a list, from another list

Tags: python, list, element

I set up a series of 'for' loops and can now determine 3 values as a result of this. I now want to store the 3 values in a list. This is what I've attempted so far:

```
output = []                 # creates empty list
k = 0  
for i in range(len(GPS[0])-1):          # for loop through 1 column of GPS .csv this is the time
    for j in range(len(Data[0])-1):     # for loop through 1st column of Data .csv this is the time
        if GPS[1,i] == Data[1,j]:       # if loop, so if time in GPS = time in Data
              delta = i-j               # finds the difference between values
              #print(i,j, delta)          # prints row in i that matches row in j, and also the difference between them
              #print(GPS[1,i],Data[1,j])  # prints the Height from GPS and time from Data  
              output[k] = output.append(GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j])
              k=k+1
print(output)
```

Basically I want the output to be a list contains the 3 values `GPS[1,i]`, `GPS[0,i]` and `Data[0,j]`. I've tried to use append but I can't seem to get anywhere with it, all I get is a list of 'none'

Comment: Do you want to add the three elements to the list, or add a **tuple** with the three elements to the list?

Comment: `append()` edits a list in place and returns `None` - hence when you do `output[k] = output.append(GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j])`, you're actually setting `output[k] = None`

Comment: add 3 elements to the list, so that in the future I can call upon individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not right:

```
output[k] = output.append(GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j])
```

Use `output.extend` instead. So your code might look like this:

```
output = []                 # creates empty list
k = 0  
for i in range(len(GPS[0])-1):          # for loop through 1 column of GPS .csv this is the time
    for j in range(len(Data[0])-1):     # for loop through 1st column of Data .csv this is the time
        if GPS[1,i] == Data[1,j]:       # if loop, so if time in GPS = time in Data
              delta = i-j               # finds the difference between values
              #print(i,j, delta)          # prints row in i that matches row in j, and also the difference between them
              #print(GPS[1,i],Data[1,j])  # prints the Height from GPS and time from Data  
              output.extend([GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j]])
              k=k+1
print(output)
```

Further, if you want to append a tuple to the output you could do `output.append([GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j]])` instead.

Extend will add elements to list itself

```
>>> output = []
>>> output.extend([1,2,3])
>>> output
[1, 2, 3]
```

Append will make a new list and add new list to your list

```
>>> output = []
>>> output.append([1,2,3])
>>> output
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `output[k]` as `append` itself adds them to `output`. To be honest, you don't even need `k` as `k` is just equal to the length of `output`.

`append` can't take multiple arguments like you are trying to do. If you want to add the three bits of data together as a tuple, use:

`output.append((GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j]))`

EDIT: since you want to just add them to the list, use `extend`

`output.extend([GPS[1,i], GPS[0,i], Data[1,j]])`